# Oracle Sql query to get manager to employee relation

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table structure like this in which employee to manager relation is defined

```
EMP_ID    SUP_ID     START_DATE    END_DATE
emp1      sup1       01-JAN-2012   30-JAN-2012
emp1      sup2       01-FEB-2012   28-FEB-2012
emp2      sup1       01-JAN-2012   28-FEB-2012
```

I need a query to get all the employees under a manager as of the sysdate.

ie if im executing it on jan with mgr id sup1 it should return emp1 and emp2
if it is on feb it should return emp2 only.

I tried writing the query using joins but its not working and im confused on where to put what conditions.

Comment: Are `SUP_ID` values from the same domain as `EMP_ID` - i.e. does the table represent a hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should surely work?

```
select * from employees
where sysdate between start_date and end_date
and sup_id = 'sup1';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from employees where sup_id = 'sup1' and start_date = trunc(sysdate);
```